# Quantifying the magnetic force on a single iron atom

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, atoms, magnetic-moment

If a single iron atom exists in a non-uniform magnetic field, could one measure the force on it simply by multiplying the magnetic dipole moment of the atom by the change in the magnetic field?

Comment: The force will be proportional to the magnetic moment times the magnetic field gradient, which is probably what you mean: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/physics-experiment/app5.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (very) short answer is "yes". Force is

$$\vec F=\vec \mu \cdot \nabla \vec B$$

This is true for individual particles as much as for macroscopic objects.